# What should I do if the "this question already has an answer here" does not give me the answer

Tags: discussion, support

I have seen many times that questions get closed for awnsers because they are a duplicate or it gets a "the question might be answerd here" link to another question. but what if the question is seen as a duplicate or already answered but the conditions in the questions are just a bit differend making the answer not a good one or incomplete or something.

how should someone handle this situation? what if he has really low reputation and does not have anything to do against it?

Comment: That is described in the [help center under reopen-questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: haha this one is a duplicate though